# Powershell Downloadstring giving timeout - can I set timeout or use a different method?

Tags: powershell, webclient, downloadstring

I have two urls that trigger a webservice. I need to schedule triggering these as tasks. So this is how I scheduled the first one.

```
$url="https://dd.com/dd/RunScheduledTask.aspx?Action=executespecificscheduledmacro&Macro=fetch"
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$url");
```

The above works. I tried invoke-webrequest but it doesn't seem to actually trigger the webservce.

I need to trigger a second web service by going to a different url. Using the method above I get

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"
```

The second url looks like

https://dd.com/dd/RunScheduledTask.aspx?Action=executespecificscheduledmacro&Macro=import

Is there a way to set the timeout / expose the timeout or another method I can use?

I just need to load the url and it runs a webservice. It doesn't load a page or anything. Obviously wanting to run in background.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` has a `-TimeoutSec`...

Comment: I'm not on PS 7. I was thinking of installing it as a last resort and using invoke-restmethod.

Comment: The parameter is also available in Windows PowerShell 5.1

Comment: I've had major issues with restmethod outside ps7

Comment: I'm going to test RestMethod when I get a window of time. I tested but it got interrupted by someone. Looked like it was going though.

Comment: RestMethod seems to work. I have the timesec as default but will adjust. Default is 0 /indefinite.